# Mount LED Batten light to allow Rotational Direction change at various positions/ angles up & down using Hinge type mechanism?

Tags: electrical, wood, light-fixture, metal

I've got this LED batten light to replace old Tube lights.

It's pretty light in weight and is full electrical fixture in itself, not needing electrical fixtures like before.

It simply mounts on 2 tiny metal clips that can be screwed into a surface.

- Links & pics updated

[image: LED Batten Light mounted on Clip]
[image: Simple Metal Clip]

Now I'd like to be able to direct the positioning of it from Vertical up to Horizontal to vertical down.

Ideally being able to hold at any angle between +/- 90.

I've shared it's main unit is mounted on.  I'd like to figure a fixture or way by which the clips can be screwed on to it instead of directly to wall or wood surface.

A simple up & down would be via a simple butt Hinge but I'm hoping to find something better to angle it as I see fit.

Updated info & thoughts:

Now instead of the Metal part of Clip that goes directly to a wall or mounting surface I'm hoping for some kind of simple metallic hinge like attachment that could become the "rotatable / adjustable/ swing up- down" mount in the middle.

Any particular existing simple hardware fixtures that could do this for me?

Update:

- Apparently there are some "Torsion / Friction Positioning Hinges" that could help this scenario. I'm wondering if thats the only way or they are also called something else or similar components?

Comment: Is it mains powered?  Does your planned use conform with the labeling and instructions?

Comment: @Harper instructions are 2 simple clips & screw on to mounting surface directly. I'm just trying to add some direction adjustability by having the clips attach to some kind of hinge

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer that helped you the most, or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Comment: @FreeMan Unresolved and shelved for lack of finding a simple fitting locally in Asia that would do the job

Answer (score 1):

I'd consider fabricating a fixture from wood.

Two end pieces fixed to ceiling joists.

A wooden  batten between the end-pieces, secured axially by screw or bolt with the clearance hole in the end pieces allowing rotation.

Flexible cord to a decorative cover for the wiring box / ceiling box. Sufficient slack to allow for rotation of fixture.

Maybe wave or Belleville washers to control friction of rotational movement.

[image: diagram of suggestion]

Perhaps having a circular adjustment knob for angle at one end would allow for better balance.

Comment: Yes. Fabricate a piece of furniture that moves and can fully mount/enclose the luminaire, without the luminaire being any part of the mechanism, nor tge luminaire or its cord interfering with any part of the mechanism.    Have it move just like you want.  Then affix luminaire, using cord/plug connection, change old light socket to a receptacle.

Comment: Thanks for this lovely idea but as you may notice with the pictures now, I need something much simpler but I have no idea where to start besides think of a simple Hinge to mount the mounting clips on

Answer (score 1):

Mount the clips to a piece of EMT pipe using elevator bolts, or to PVC pipe with flathead machine screws tapped into the pipe on the far side.

Mount the pipe to the wall with Conduit hangers which stand off the wall a little bit, snugged so the pipe can still move.

If you have problems with the pipe walking out of the standoff clips, put hose clamps just inboard of the standoffs.